# css - change color of the cursor

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply style to the cursor.
Below is the code

```
 <span style="cursor:help ; color:red; font-size:40px;">Help</span><br>
```

When i tried color:red it changed the text 'Help' to red color.
How to make the cursor red?

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/user_123/aoubt7yv/

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `color:` is purely for text

Comment: guys, don't downvote, he really is asking because he don't know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cursors aren't really stylable like you might expect at least not using properties that would traditionally target DOM elements.

The best approach would be to set the `cursor` attribute to a URL that contains your preferred cursor as seen below :

```
/* This will change your cursor to the image at your URL */
cursor: url('{your-red-cursor-url}'), auto;
```

**Example**

[image]

```css
.red-cursor {
  color:red; 
  font-size:40px;
  cursor: url('http://www.spacebug.50webs.com/visible.gif'), auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='red-cursor'>
    Testing
  </div>
```

Comment: cursor not fully displaying in Firefox

Comment: @dippas It may be related to the size of the image that was used in my example. There are [a few known limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property#Limitations) regarding using URLs for cursors, most of which relate to the size of the target image.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, just trying to tell you to maybe use other image, but meanwhile my PC crashed `:/` and couldn't edit the omment

Comment: Hmm. What does it look like on your machine? I tried it on Firefox and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You will probably need to do it as an image as `color` is for changing the color of text.

You can try an image like this:

`.cursor { cursor: url(images/my-cursor-design.png), auto; }`

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the custom cursor image with an image with red background.

```
 <span style="cursor:url('put-red-image-here'), auto ; font-size:40px;">Help</span><br>
```

You could use JavaScript, but I believe this is a simpler option.