Change cursor color on hover in css
So my question is:- Can we change the Colour of Cursor pointer during hover state of a button? If Yes, then How?
eg. The viewer's cursor default color is white. But I want it to be black when the viewer hovers on the button of my page.

Have you looked at the answers given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327290/css-change-color-of-the-cursor
